# Fit background image to div completly

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have checkout out some example like [example](http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/wGRD7/)

I tried different methods with `background-size` changing it to `cover or contain` but how can i achieve that background image should cover the entire div

Here you can see the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wGRD7/2819/) where background image is not covered entire div

Comment: why is downvote please explain i will improve...

Comment: I'm added an answer ,don't forget to tick it if it's helps you :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gave up Check now. I have added some css property in it.

```css
#imagecontainer {
    
    background: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg") no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid;
    
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagecontainer">
  hi
  dadsa
  <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
  dasd
  asd
  as
  d
  asd
  asd
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `contain` with `fill` or ``... like this
But know that when using **fill** the image will be slightly cropped...

```
//background-size:fill;
//background-size:cover;
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wGRD7/2822/ i changed fiddle as you can see background image is broken

Comment: oh ok sorry I didnt see

Answer (score 0):

use  **background-size:cover;** instead of  **background-size:contain;**

```css
#imagecontainer {
    
    background: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg")  no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-size:cover;
    /*background-size:contain;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="imagecontainer">
  hi
  dadsa
  <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
   <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div> <div>
  dsa sad sadasd sa
  </div>
  dasd
  asd
  as
  d
  asd
  asd
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change background:contain

```
background-size:fill;
```

or

```
background-size:cover;
```

both are covered the background image in the entire div.

Answer (score 0):

To scale the background image to fit inside the div:

```
background-size: contain;
```

To scale the background image to cover the whole div:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Also, `background-repeat: round` provides the best result. However, it only works on Chrome for the time being.